# How can merge uncommited changes with other branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I have the following scenario:

1. I have two branches: *master* and *testing*
2. I checked out the master branch and modified some files
3. Then I realised that I should have done those changes on the testing branch and not the master branch

I don't want to commit on master branch. How can have those changes made on the testing branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout testing
```

or, if git refuses to do that

```
git stash
git checkout testing
git stash pop
```

Comment: More info on stashing, which is the key concept here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing